# Entendendo parâmetros lambda de um delegate em uma função

Tags: c#, delegate

Tenho a função abaixo. Só gostaria de entender quem é X e que valores ele vai atingindo no decorrer da função. Não consegui pegar no debug. Não precisam dizer exata,ente os valores literalmente, mas como ele sendo aringido. Estou estudando e quero entender tudo isso.

```
public int qualquerCoisa(int tamanho)
        {
            Func<int, int> calcFib = null;

            calcFib = x => (x - 1 + x - 2);

            return calcFib(tamanho);
        }
```

Comment: O código acima, eu sei que está errado. Só coloquei para dizer o que eu estou querendo fazer. O resultado seria: 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34, ou seja, uma lista ou array retornados.

Comment: Favor, não envie código pronto. Só preciso entender para eu poder fazer e chegar às minhas conclusões.

Comment: Não devia ter editado a pergunta. Ela agora pede algo diferente do inicialmente pedido, deixando as resposta dadas de alguma forma sem sentido. Em vez de editar deveria dar esta pergunta como encerrada e criar uma nova.

Comment: ok, vou remover a edição e encerrar e fazer outra.

Answer (score 2):

O `X` representa o parâmetro que e passado para a função `calcFib`. Se reescrever a função `calcFib` como um método ficaria:

```
public int calcFic(int x)
{
    return x - 1 + x -2;
}
```

No caso do código que colocou, `X` vai receber o valor de `tamanho`.

Comment: Ou seja, no caso específico, ele não percorre até o valor máximo, começando em um determinado valor. Teria que passar, um array ou lista, para que ele fosse percorrendo até o valor de tamanho, falando especificamente no caso acima.

Comment: Exactamente. Caso queira que a função seja executada para uma lista pode: ou criar um ciclo `for` e passar os valores um a a um para a função. Ou então mudar a função para aceitar uma lista/array e dentro da função executar o ciclo `for`.

Answer (score 2):

`Func<int,int>` declara um [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx) que representa uma função que recebe um parâmetro do tipo `int` e retorna um valor do tipo `int`.

Pegando no seu exemplo o resultado de `return calcFib(tamanho);` será:

```
int resultado = tamanho - 1 + tamanho - 2;
```

O valor que `x` recebe é aquele que é passado à função.